# Determining the best evaluation metric for linear regression

Tags: regression, linear, model-evaluation, methodology, mse

I'm trying to evaluate the model results that I got from linear regression.
For some models, I get a high r$^2$ (good) [89] but also a high mse (poor) [1000].
and in other cases for some models I get the reverse, a low r$^2$ score(poor) and a low mse (good).

I'm confused as to which metric to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

$R^2$ is always going to be a number between 0 and 1.  MSE is going to depend on the scale of your $y$-variable.  For example, SAT scores are in the thousands, so it would be normal to see an MSE in the hundreds of thousands.  GPA, on the other hand, is between 0 and 4.  You would never see an MSE in even the hundreds.

MSE as an evaluation metric is only useful when comparing against other models that have the same dependent variable.  And even then, it isn't interpretable like $R^2$ is.

Comment: Note that $R^2<0$ is possible when you exclude an intercept.